# Does this analytic function is zero?

Tags: laurent-series, analytic-functions

Suppose $f$ is a complex analytic in a neighbourhood of $0$ such that $\forall k\in \mathbb{N}(\exists n_0 (\forall n>n_0( |f(a_n)|\leq {|a_{n}|}^k)))$ where $a_n$ is a non-zero sequence converging to $0$, can we say that $f$ is $0$?

I tried for specific examples of $a_n$, it feels like true when this statement "function matches at all points if laurent series matches at infinitely many points with an accumulation point" is true.

Comment: Suppose $$g(z) = \sum_{k = m}^{\infty} c_k z^k$$ with $c_m \neq 0$. What can you deduce about $\lvert g(a_n)\rvert$?

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't get. What can be deduced from a general power series?

Comment: That depends on what we know or assume about the power series. Here, you want to conclude that $f\equiv 0$. One way to show that is to show that a holomorphic function in a neighbourhood of $0$ that doesn't vanish identically can't have the property that is given for $f$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am not getting any useful bound

Comment: And if you write $$\sum_{k = m}^{\infty} c_k z^k = z^m \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} c_{m+k} z^k\,?$$

Comment: @DanielFischer I have no idea,

Comment: If you look at $\dfrac{g(a_n)}{a_n^m}$? Aside: there are some absolute value signs missing in the question, it ought to be $\lvert f(a_n)\rvert \leqslant \lvert a_n\rvert^k$; inequalities between complex numbers generally don't make sense.

Comment: @DanielFischer yeah got it $c_{m}$ should be zero if $g$ satisfies the given condition